# Per-class configuration of spring data rest repository export

Tags: java, spring-data-rest

We have a REST API application based on Spring Data REST. We have many types of data exposed as spring data repositories marked with the `@RepositoryRestResource`. We would like to control precisely which data types are exposed at runtime, as we will have several installations with slightly different requirements.

How can we achieve fine grained control at runtime over which repositories are exposed by Spring Data REST?

Our naive attempt was to use the `export` parameter in `@RepositoryRestResource` with an expression, but we can't see how to make that work - the expression evaluates to a string, not a boolean.

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = "${app.exportStudy}")
public interface StudyRepository<Study> extends MongoRepository<Study,String> {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of solving this is to replace the repository detection strategy.

First, use an object to store your configuration:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("app.repository")
@Data
public class AppRepositoryConfig {
    private boolean exportStudy = true;
    private boolean exportSample = true;
    ...
}
```

Second, amend the behaviour of the stock RepositoryDetectionStrategy to take into account your configuration:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AppRepositoryDetectionStrategyConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @NonNull private AppRepositoryConfig appRepositoryConfig;

@Override
public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
    RepositoryDetectionStrategy rds = config.getRepositoryDetectionStrategy();

    config.setRepositoryDetectionStrategy(
            repositoryDetectionStrategy(rds)
    );
}

private RepositoryDetectionStrategy repositoryDetectionStrategy(
        RepositoryDetectionStrategy repositoryDetectionStrategy) {
    RepositoryDetectionStrategy rds = metadata -> {

            boolean defaultExportSetting = repositoryDetectionStrategy.isExported(metadata);

            if  (metadata.getDomainType().equals(Study.class)) {
                return (appRepositoryConfig.isExportStudy()) ? defaultExportSetting : false; 
            }
            ...
            return defaultExportSetting;
    };

    return rds;
}
```